# Como posso copiar uma maquina do android studio para outra maquina, sem precisar instalar o android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk, emulador, avd

Instalei o android studio em minha maquina e criei uma maquina com android para emular as aplicações, mas agora eu quero pegar somente esta maquina que criei e colocar em outro computador, estou tentando, mas quando tento executar acontece isso:

```
C:\Users\usuario\Desktop\Sdk\emulator>emulator.exe -avd whatsapp
PANIC: Unknown AVD name [whatsapp], use -list-avds to see valid list.
ANDROID_SDK_HOME is defined but there is no file whatsapp.ini in $ANDROID_SDK_HOME\avd
(Note: Directories are searched in the order $ANDROID_AVD_HOME, $ANDROID_SDK_HOME\avd and $HOME\.android\avd)
```

Se executo:

```
C:\Users\usuario\Desktop\Sdk\emulator>emulator.exe -list-avds
```

Não retorna nada.

Adicionei nas variáveis de ambiente ANDROID_SDK_HOME com o caminho novo onde esta a maquina, mas apresenta o mesmo erro acima.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se eu executar este mesmo comando na pasta default do android studio que esta instalado na minha maquina, funciona normalmente.

Como posso copiar uma maquina do android studio para outra maquina, sem precisar instalar o android studio?

Eu estou procurando algo do tipo:

```
emulator.exe -avd <caminho_da_maquina>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por **padrão** os AVDs são criados em `$HOME/.android/avd`. No Windows provavelmente é algo como `C:\Users\MeuUsuario\.android\avd`.

É possível criar a variável de ambiente `$ANDROID_AVD_HOME` para alterar o caminho padrão.

---

Os AVDs salvos são compostos por um diretório e um arquivo `.ini`. Se você tiver um AVD chamado `whatsapp`, existirá:

- um diretório `$HOME/.android/avd/whatsapp.avd`
- um arquivo `$HOME/.android/avd/whatsapp.ini`

Para mover o AVD entre máquinas, basta copiar estes dois itens.

Para rodar o AVD em outra máquina, deverá ser instalada nela a mesma imagem de sistema que foi usada para criar o AVD.

Comment: Vou testar na outra maquina.